# Javascript Target link state

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a bit of javascript that toggles two divs with two separate links, I wanted to add a little image next to the selected link say for instance if you select div 1 to be viewed the link would have a litle bullet next to it and if you select div 2 the div 2 would have a bullet on it. Heres the script can anyone help please :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">



  <style type='text/css'>


  </style>


  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js'></script>

<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function(){

    $('a[id^="link"]').click(function(){
        var vid_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("link", "#testVid");
        $('div[id^="testVid"]').hide();
        $(vid_id).show();
    });
    $('span[id^="close"]').click(function(){
        var vid_id = $(this).attr("id").replace("close", "#testVid");
        $(vid_id).hide();
    });
});

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <a href="#" id="link1">Click Link 1</a><br />
    <a href="#" id="link2">Click Link 2</a><br />

    <div id="testVid1" style="background:pink; height:300px">Test Vid Div 1<br /><br /><span id="close1">CLOSE 1</span></div>
    <div id="testVid2" style="display:none;background:pink; height:300px">Test Vid Div 2<br /><br /><span id="close2">CLOSE 2</span></div>

</div>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in various ways.  I can think of three off the top of my head, and I'm sure there are more.

1. Background images and padding
2. content:before
3. Altering the DOM dynamically (not recommended)

The idea in #1 and #2 is to change the CSS style of the selected element.  For #1, you would define styles something like this:

```
.selected {
    background-image: url(myselectedimage.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
    padding-left: 20px; /* or whatever the size of your image is */
}
```

For #2, you would use the following:

```
.selected:before {
    content: "\u2219"; /* bullet */
}
```

Then, you can do something like this to remove the .selected class from everything, and add it to the selected link, when a link is clicked:

```
$('a[id^="link"]').click(function(e){
    $('a[id^="link"]').removeClass('selected');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('selected');
    ...
});

$('span[id^="close"]').click(function(){
    $('a[id^="link"]').removeClass('selected');
    ...
});
```

The advantage to approach #1 is that almost all modern browsers support it without trouble.  The advantage to #2 is that it's more flexible -- you can add text, images, attributes, all kinds of things, but be warned that browser support can be inconsistent.  Since you're already using CSS3 selectors (^=), you're probably OK.  See [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-content/) for more info.

Approach #3 involves inserting and removing HTML from before the link.  It's possible, but clunky.  It's how we used to do things before CSS2 and 3 came along. :)  I wouldn't recommend it, but occasionally it's the only way to get things done in a reliably cross-browser fashion (probably not in this case).  In order to do that, insert a <span> tag before each link, with an ID that is computable from the link ID (or you could use CSS selectors to find the sibling).  Then use JQuery's .html() method to insert HTML into it, e.g.:

```
<span id="bullet-link1"></span><a href="#" id="link1">Click Link 1</a><br />
...

<script lang="text/javascript">
$('a[id^="link"]').click(function(e) {
    $('span[id^="bullet-"]').html('');
    $('#bullet-' + e.currentTarget.id).html('&#8226;');
    ...
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thats great thankyou.... any chance you could pop it into a jsfiddle just so i can learn the process of it fully. Your a gem :)